# How to make infinite loop for JQuery library?

Tags: jquery

I have a Jquery code

```
<script>
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
  Typed.new('.element', {
    strings: ["First sentence.", "Second sentence."],
    typeSpeed: 0
  });
});
 </script>
```

I need to make it infinite repeat, I tryed to put the code in while loop

```
<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
  while(1){

  Typed.new('.element', {
    strings: ["First sentence.", "Second sentence."],
    typeSpeed: 0
  });
  }
});
 </script>
```

But it doe not work..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use **setInterval** methods :

```
<script>
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
 setInterval(function(){
     Typed.new('.element', {
      strings: ["First sentence.", "Second sentence."],
        typeSpeed: 0
       });          
   },100);
 });
</script>
```

sample code : [setInterval sample](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

Comment: it seems, that there is a typo, because it does not work

Answer (score 0):

U can create infinite loop in js like that:

```
function selfInvoke() {
alert(1);
selfInvoke();
}

selfInvoke();//but with time u can get an error
```

Better solution to use setInterval:

```
function myFunction() {
    setInterval(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 500);
}
myFunction();
```